# Using Phoenix Elixir render assigns to include partials

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In my app.html.eex file I have:

`<%= assigns[:feet]%>`

and in my controller I have:

  `def index(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, "index.html", feet: "feet.html")
  end`

I want to do this so I can import different feets in different sub views. Ex:

`def :edit(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, "edit.html", feet: "edit-feet.html")
  end`

Unfortunately, it just prints "feet.html" instead of importing feet.html.

Is this possible some how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `Phoenix.View.render/3`:

```
<%= render YourView, @feet, [] %>
```

If setting `feet` is optional and you don't want to render anything if it's not present, you can do:

```
<%= if feet = assigns[:feet] do %>
  <%= render YourView, feet, [] %>
<% end %>
```

Replace `YourView` with the View that contains `feet.html` and `edit-feet.html`.

If you need to pass any `assigns` to those templates, you can replace `[]` with the values you want to pass:

```
<%= render YourView, @feet, foo: "bar", baz: "quux" %>
```

Comment: `    
<%= if feet = assigns[:feet] do %>
  <%= render @view_module, @feet, assigns %>
<% end %>
`
was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @mchavezi Pedantic comment: If you're using `@feet`, you don't need to do `feet =`. Or you should just use `feet` inside the `if`. The version in your comment has an unused variable.